# Running an Ignite Cluster

Tags: ignite

I have a 12 node Apache Ignite cluser. My application code runs along with Ignite and are both loaded into the same JVM. I am using SprinBoot 1.4.1. I was wondering if there would be some advice on whether I can consider to use [peerClassLoading](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#DFLT_P2P_ENABLED) to allow to support the following rough deployment plan:

**Node 1 :** Will run as a master/primary node (springboot+other java code + ignite jar(s))

**Nodes 2-11 :** Will run as headless ignite nodes (no springboot/other java app code)

Currently I am using the default setting of `false` for `peerClassLoading`.

Please let me know your thoughts.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

With peer-class-loading enabled, you don't have to manually deploy your Java code on each node in the grid and re-deploy it each time it changes.

So, if you want to deploy your code only to one node, you should use peerClassLoading.

[Here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/zero-deployment) is doc about it.

Comment: How will this work with a Spring ApplicationContext in terms of it being needed to be loaded cluster wide ?